# simple SQL query giving Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting Invalid use of group function and how to stop it?

```
SELECT Name, Message
FROM flux_chat_messages
WHERE id >= ( MAX( id ) -5 )
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use `MAX()` in a `WHERE`. So wrap it in a subquery like:

```
SELECT Name, Message
FROM flux_chat_messages
WHERE id >= (SELECT MAX( id ) - 5 FROM flux_chat_messages)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Also probably you could have

```
SELECT Name, Message
FROM flux_chat_messages
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

and reverse the results in your program (or use another subquery for that)

Comment: Ah, I had to select the max(id) -5 to turn it into a useable number. Thank you. I'll accept when I can :)