# MySQL find if the last payment is expired

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table `payments` I handle both payments users have made & trials. Trials are set as paid but the total is zero (0.00$), like:

```
ID | Subscription | Plan | Total | Paid | Paid at | Expires at
1    1              1      0.00    1      null      2020-11-05
```

When the trial is about to expire, the user is forced to purchase a plan, the following row is created:

```
ID | Subscription | Plan | Total | Paid | Paid at     | Expires at
1    1              1      0.00    1      null          2020-11-05
2    1              1      15.00   1      2020-11-06    2020-12-06
```

As you can see the `total` is no longer zero and the variable `paid_at` is also filled. The SQL code should read the row number 2.

What I need now is to verify if the last payment is expired. But before we proceed, keep in mind the following: the user may choose to purchase a plan but don't pay it right away, which means the **first** payment must be the one taken in consideration. Example:

```
ID | Subscription | Plan | Total | Paid | Paid at     | Expires at
1    1              1      0.00    1      null          2020-11-05
2    1              1      15.00   0      null          2020-12-06
```

In this case the user decided to purchase the plan, but didn't pay yet. The SQL logic should read the `expires_at` of the row number 1.

Currently my SQL code is the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM payments 
WHERE expires_at < '2020-11-06'
AND paid = true 
and subscription_id = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I know that this will never work because its always fetching the row number 1, no matter if I have more rows or not. I also know that I could select the last row that was paid and then verify through code if it has expired but I want to do it through SQL.

**EDIT 1**: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16b3f0/2) to help

I created three table `payments`, `payments_2`, `payments_3`:

1 `payments` -> everything ok!

2 `payments_2` -> everything ok! The user did not paid yet, therefore should grab the first row

3 `payments_3` incorrect data. The user has already paid and therefore the SQL should validate the last `expires_at` row

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscription_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `expires_at` date NOT NULL,
  `paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `paid_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
ALTER TABLE `payments` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

INSERT INTO payments VALUES(1, 1, 1, 0, '2020-11-05', 1, null);

CREATE TABLE `payments_2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscription_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `expires_at` date NOT NULL,
  `paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `paid_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
ALTER TABLE `payments_2` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

INSERT INTO payments_2 VALUES(1, 1, 1, 0, '2020-11-05', 1, null);
INSERT INTO payments_2 VALUES(2, 1, 1, 15.00, '2020-12-06', 1, null);

CREATE TABLE `payments_3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscription_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `expires_at` date NOT NULL,
  `paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `paid_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
ALTER TABLE `payments_3` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

INSERT INTO payments_3 VALUES(1, 1, 1, 0, '2020-11-05', 1, null);
INSERT INTO payments_3 VALUES(2, 1, 1, 15.00, '2020-12-06', 1, '2020-11-06 15:00:00');
```

Comment: More comprehensive sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: get the MAX(`Expires at`) date and check with current date, if bigger the user has to buy a ticket or whatvever noeed for fancy sql

Comment: @GordonLinoff added SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Incidentally, if 'total' relates to money, then it's unlikely to be DOUBLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** with the hint of @nbk. In MySQL [we can't use MAX in a where](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9661724/3355243), therefore:

```
SELECT *
FROM `payments`
where subscription_id = 1 
  and (SELECT MAX(expires_at) 
         FROM payments 
        WHERE subscription_id = 1 AND paid = true) < CURDATE()
```

Comment: I think you can do better!